# CSS Corner radius not rendering correctly on Firefox Mac

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with this CSS

```
.tabelaTripla {
    border: 0px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

.tabelaTripla tr {
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 40px;
}

.tabelaTripla th, td{
    border: 0px;
    width: 33%;
}

.tabelaTripla td{
    border: 0px;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    word-wrap:  break-word;
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

this works correctly on all browsers but I see this on Firefox for Mac.

Firefox is not rounding the coloring of the columns.

[image]

---

My HTML code for this is simple:

```
<table class="tabelaTripla">
  <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

just a table with 3 columns

Comment: Please provide your html code as well. Also, the `table` tag description says "do not use". Use the `html-table` tag instead.

Comment: here you have it but there is not really to see because it is just a table with 1 column with 3 columns that I just created. So it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still quite not sure where you went wrong, because you haven't provided the CSS for the colours, but you can just set `.tabelaTripla` to `background-color: yellow;` and then set the `.tabelaTripla td` to `background-color: white;`. (Obviously you can change these colours to whatever you want)

```css
.tabelaTripla {
  border: 0px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 20px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.tabelaTripla tr {
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 40px;
}
.tabelaTripla th, td {
  border: 0px;
  width: 33%;
}
.tabelaTripla td {
  border: 0px;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabelaTripla">
  <tr>
    <td>AAA</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
    <td>CCC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above snippet will produce this effect:

[image]

**Edit:** By the way, I am also using FireFox on Mac OSX so this should work for you as well.

Comment: @SpaceDog How's my answer?

Comment: not working for me. I am checking if there is another css interferring

Comment: THANKS! WORKING NOW!!

Comment: I have [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185182/fighting-with-css-to-make-a-table-with-different-heights-and-colors) for you... 