# Fighting with CSS to make a table with different heights and colors

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with 3 columns.

Inside every column there is a table with 3 lines.

I want to make this second table like this:

1. first row is 80 px height
2. second row is 40 px height and has a black background.
3. third row has variable height
4. This table must be vertically aligned to top. It is not. It is vertically aligned to center. Meaning the internal table is at the vertical center of the cell of the outside table.

So, this is the code:

```css
.tabelaTresLinhasInterna {
border: 0px;
table-layout: fixed;
font-size: 0.9em;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto auto auto;
}


.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(1) {
height:80px;
}
.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000;
height:40px;
}

.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(3) {
height:auto;
}


.tabelaTripla {
border: 0px;
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: 100%;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 20px;
font-size: 0.7em;
line-height: 1.3em;
background-color: #fafafa;
}

.tabelaTripla tr {
padding: 40px;
margin: 40px;
}

.tabelaTripla th, td{
border: 0px;
 width: 33%;
}

.tabelaTripla td{
border: 0px;
width: 33%;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
word-wrap: break-word;
padding: 40px;
border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabelaTripla">
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table class="tabelaTresLinhasInterna">
        <tr><td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 3</td></tr>
      </table>
  </td>
    <td>COLUMN 2</td>
    <td>COLUMN 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The internal table is ignoring the CSS...

Comment: You should add `vertical-align: top;` to the outer table's `td`. Though you won't see it working until the `td` is larger than the table contained within. By default the `td` of the outer table is going to stretch to match the height of it's content.

Comment: duh! you are right. I forgot that align center there. The vertical alignment is now working. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the outer table's `td`.

For the row heights, apply the height to the `td` instead of the `tr`, i.e. `.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(1) td { height:80px; }`.

```css
.tabelaTresLinhasInterna {
  border: 0px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto auto auto;
}

.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(1) td {
  height: 80px;
}

.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(2) td {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 40px;
}

.tabelaTripla {
  border: 0px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 20px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.tabelaTripla tr {
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.tabelaTripla th,
td {
  border: 0px;
  width: 33%;
}

.tabelaTripla td {
  border: 0px;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabelaTripla">
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table class="tabelaTresLinhasInterna">
        <tr>
          <td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>COLUMN 2</td>
    <td>COLUMN 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok. like I said, that covers number 4 of my question. What about the other 3 items? Thanks

Comment: Set the height on the `td` instead of the `tr`. `tr` are notoriously limited in the styles they accept.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that your styles for `.tabelaTripla td` are inherited by `td`s of the internal table.

So that:

1. minimal height of the first row is 80px, but inner content makes it bigger because of inherited `padding: 40px`
2. same reason for height. Background color applies but covers with `background-color: #fdfdfd;` from the rules mentioned above
3. it's all right here
4. same problem, `vertical-align: middle;` inherited from top-level `td`

Try to use more concrete and specific rules.

Answer (score 1):

padding is forcing the height of the cells... yo have to change the td display property in something like "display:block" but other modifications are needed.

By setting the padding of the inner table to zero, the height of the cell dosn't have a "minimum height"

.tabelaTripla .tabelaTresLinhasInterna td {
  padding:0px
}

My advice is to use a grid system and you will get this thing in a responsive way and especially with less effort.

```css
.tabelaTresLinhasInterna {
border: 0px;
table-layout: fixed;
font-size: 0.9em;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto auto auto;
}

.tabelaTripla .tabelaTresLinhasInterna td {
  padding:0px
}

.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
word-wrap: break-word;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(1) {
height:80px;
}
.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000;
height:40px;
}

.tabelaTresLinhasInterna tr:nth-child(3) {
height:auto;
}


.tabelaTripla {
border: 0px;
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: 100%;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 20px;
font-size: 0.7em;
line-height: 1.3em;
background-color: #fafafa;
}

.tabelaTripla tr {
padding: 40px;
margin: 40px;
}

.tabelaTripla th, td{
border: 0px;
 width: 33%;
}

.tabelaTripla td{
border: 0px;
width: 33%;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
word-wrap: break-word;
padding: 40px;
border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
border-radius: 20px;
background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabelaTripla">
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table class="tabelaTresLinhasInterna">
        <tr><td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>INTERNAL TABLE LINE 3</td></tr>
      </table>
  </td>
    <td>COLUMN 2</td>
    <td>COLUMN 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```